# Why are some images not able to convert from ARGB_8888 to RGB_565?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am working with bitmaps in Android, and I am reading Android documentation about bitmap. There is a parameter in Bitmap.Options called inPreferredConfig

The description of inPreferredConfig shows below:

If this is non-null, the decoder will try to decode into this internal configuration. If it is null, or the request cannot be met, the decoder will try to pick the best matching config based on the system's screen depth, and characteristics of the original image such as if it has per-pixel alpha (requiring a config that also does).

Therefore, I want to know when the image cannot be converted to RGB_565?

I try to set some images with RGB_565 but some of them show ARGB_8888 config. I also know that only ARGB_8888 works with transparency. Another fact is that there is less description in Android documentation about this aspect.